# Hadoop JobClient.runJob: Cannot initialize cluster - Misleading error message(?) and a proposed solution

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

(I've now solved this issue by adding a dependency as specified at the end of this post, but wondering if there is a better alternative or if I've missed something important?)

When trying to run a mapreduce job, the line

```
JobClient.runJob(conf)
```

gives the following error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your     configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:826)
```

My set-up is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Reduce.class);          
    conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name","yarn");
    conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.address","s17.myserver.com:10020");
    conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address","s17.myserver.com:19888");

    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address","s6.myserver.com:8032");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address","s6.myserver.com:8030");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address","s6.myserver.com:8031");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address","s6.myserver.com:8033");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address","s6.myserver.com:8088");

    /// error on the following line
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

After spending considerable time trying to check and re-check my configurations, I've managed to solve the problem by adding the following dependency to my project:

hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient

Am I missing something here or is the error message just a particularly misleading one?

Answer (score 0):

This type of configuration should have been done by your cluster admin and provided as part of yarn-site.  It shouldn't need to be added by each job.  That being said, the error message is not particularly helpful and could be improved, but that's true about pretty much all error messages in Hadoop...

Comment: wow that's a pretty old question. There's a patch for it though: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6240